# How to filter the range using Axlsx with filters on some columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, axlsx

I am generating a spreadsheet using Axlsx gem. My data table has more than 10 columns but I have to add filters to first 5 columns only.

```
sheet.auto_filter = "A5:E20"
```

The problem is that these filters works only on 5 columns not on the whole table which has 10 columns. So for example when I sort the table by the first column only cells in these first 5 columns are sorted and the other cells are not touched.  Is there a way to have filters on some columns but makes filtering working on the whole table?

Comment: Do you have content in all columns? axlsx can do nothing with a cell if no content was defined. Use a nil ou "" (empty string) to at least provide content to the cell and see if works.

Comment: Yes I do. Below each column there a numeric values